# Edit JavaScript code in chrome and reload page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, chromium

Very often I hack and play with the JavaScript code on some website. Many times JavaScript code is secured in a function:

```
(function(){
    var = ...
    ...
}());
```

and I cannot access the object defined in that scope.

Moreover such code is only executed once, when the page loads, thus modifying it with the chromium/google-chrome developer console (Sources toool) is useless.

Is there any simple way to live-edit some JavaScript code in a page and reload the page so that it runs the modified code?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using something like Tampermonkey https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en

the Chrome equivalent of Firefox's Greasemonkey

EDIT: you could use this in combination with adblock to disable the loading of the script you are targeting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919183/how-to-turn-off-one-javascript-or-disable-it-under-chrome

Comment: As far as I know (but I might be very wrong!) {Temper,Grease}Monkey allow you to run extra JavaScript code in a page. I'd like to replace the JavaScript provided by the website with code that I write; can *Monkey do it?

Comment: you could use it in combination with adblock which lets you block individual js files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919183/how-to-turn-off-one-javascript-or-disable-it-under-chrome by replicating all the .js from their file except the parts you want

Comment: I see... I was hoping chromium was able to reload the page keeping the live-edited scripts; too bad it cannot :(
I guess the only remaining solution is, as you suggest, blocking the script I want to replace, and injecting my own; +1 for the idea! I don't feel like using adblock and tampermonkey to do it, though: the solution of using a proxy to hijack the requests sounds a lot less dirty manual work to me.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it *simple*, but something like [Intercept Proxy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/intercept-proxy) might be able to do it -- replacing one file with another.

Comment: I was actually doing something very similar with Charles Proxy! Rewriting the response (in my case, replacing one version of jQuery with another) was quite simple. A link: http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: I find this idea more practical than banning the files with adBlock and adding their modified version with tampermonkey...Still I don't like how intercept-proxy is working: it's not an HTTP Proxy, it's rather an HTTP server (I have to send my browser to localhost) so cookies aren't kept, and it only forwards request to a single domain, so it doesn't work if the site I want to play with uses resources from other websites... Could anyone suggest a simple opensource hackable HTTP proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to achieve what I needed.

Using Chromium's debugger I can set a breakpoint on any statement of the source code.

Once that statement is executed, the code suspends and Chromium's console gives me access to whatever is in the stack of the current function.